# How Java threads get scheduled in kernel space?

Tags: multithreading, java, jvm-hotspot

Here is my understanding about Java threads get scheduled when java launches a thread on invoke of  `start()` api of `java.lang.Thread` class running on modern implementations of OS(like solaris 9).

[image]
Used the term `LWP` because term `kernel thread` is generally used in kernel programming to launch a thread.

So, Every `java thread` creation using `java.lang.Thread::start()` api has 1:1 map with `native thread` creation using `pthread_create()` or `thr_create()` or `CreateThread()` on POSIX, Solaris, Windows platforms respectively. In-turn, each `native thread` has 1:1 map with an LWP.

My question:

1)

Can i say, there is no Java thread scheduling policy in user space jvm to schedule java threads anymore based on 1-1 threading model in the above diagram?

2)
Supplementary:
In dual core processor scenario, Does those 2 LWP's(representing an each JVM process) have equal chance to execute simultaneously(parallel)?

*Note: As a java beginner, i need this clarity*

Comment: I think that scheduling of Threads are never done in userspaces;it's generated with request to kernel and hence,OS must be responsible for scheduling---Not sure though.

Comment: In Linux, A "Kernel Thread" is a thread that the operating system uses for its own purposes, not related to any user process (i.e., not related to your JVM).  When you're talking about Java threads that are directly managed by the operating system, it is customary to call those "native threads."

Answer (score 1):

The diagram details the inner workings of the jvm, and how it abstracts from the lower level operating system threads to the java thread model. This is how the JVM runs on the above operating systems.

To answer your questions directly:

1. ) Everytime you create a thread, you create a thread for the operating system to manage. The JVM has a layer of abstraction between you and the operating system, so that you can work with the same thread model on different systems. In general, for unoptimized java code, a java thread is an OS thread.
2. ) You don't have any guarantees on executing in parallel. Depending on the CPU load, the operating system may need the resources else where for higher priority systems. When writing multithreaded applications, write as though whatever is going on outside the thread is unknown.

If you want to know more about the java multithreaded model, I recommend this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). This book is old, but it is still relevant. It was written by the Java language architect, and it goes into details about the Java multithreading model

Comment: The java runtime optimizes bytecode at runtime. It may find that you are trying to create a thread when it would be faster to do the work in the same thread. The JVM may or may not remove the call to create a new thread despite it being there in your code.

Comment: Oops... yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Do you think JVM provides an abstraction on threading aspect? i dont think so. One really cares about, whether he runs his java code in solaris/linux/windows platform JVM, based on the native(libpthread.so/kernel32.dll/libthread.so) library that JVM uses to launch native threads and the threading model that OS provides. because OS level threading model directly impact java multi threaded application performance.

Comment: The JVM does provide an abstraction over the native libraries by simplifying them. The POSIX thread standard offers a lot more flexibility than the Java Thread class and concurrency classes provides.

Comment: i would like to know your feedback on whether this diagram make sense to you, can i picturise the working of java threads in this way? i need comments on that

Comment: I maintain a java application that connects to X number devices over the network. The architecture for the program has a thread for each device that helps keep the state. There is also a thread for the GUI and thread for managing all of the device threads. When I perform a long term process with 30 devices, windows shows 32 thread handles for my process. When I do a short lived process with 30 clocks that only operates on the logs locally, my thread handle count does not get above 5. I would say the diagram is accurate to some extent, but there are edge cases.

Answer (score -1):

Java Thread scheduling policy @ JVM level can be controlled by following options
1)UseBoundThreads
2)AdjustConcurrency
3)Java Thread Priority.

Comment: these are documented statements, can u show me the results by using these options at least using  solaris JVM for your first option.

Comment: UseBoundThreads give 1x1 feature.. without it it can be MxN
AdjustConcurrency  is used in absence of 1x1  to make sufficient lpw available for JVM.
Java thread priority also influences how thread scheduling  happen.